# How to change the Y-axis value in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Can you please guide me how to change the Y - AXIS value in Chartjs.

Kindly provide step by step procedure to change.

Comment: You might want to post what code you have so far - i.e. the one with the current y axis. Also, what exactly do you want to change in the y axis - the labels, the max and min, the step value?

Comment: Below listed is the code, In that I am able to edit only the X - AXIS VALUES. I want to give values to Y - AXIS in this code itself like X - AXIS data. Can you please guide me how i can do it. Awaiting for your reply!!!!                                                                                                                                               
<script>
var lineChartData = {
labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

Comment: datasets : [
{
fillColor : "#FFC069",
strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
pointStrokeColor : "#FF9C85",
data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
},

Comment: So you want to show the Jan, Feb... on the y axis and 65, 59... on the x axis?

Comment: Goodday my friend, I just download the (CHART.JS) from internet. I want to add the Y -AXIS VALUE to my graph like ( In code itself we can change the values of X-AXIS)  I need to change the Y - AXIS value in same method. My Y- AXIS VALUES ARE 1M, 2M, 3M, 4M. 5M.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "#FFC069",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#FF9C85",
            data: [45, 39, 40, 31, 26, 45, 10, 36, 25, 30, 2, 10]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    // adjusting your scale labels
    scaleLabel: "<%=value/10%>M",
    // adjusting your scale
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 5,
    scaleStepWidth: 10,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    // ajusting tooltips
    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value / 10 %>M",
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t0o07xbf/

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple graphs, for example bar and line chart in one. For Same value both graph should be displayed equally at the same time line chart must be over the bar chart.

Comment: Not right now, but I *think* the new version of Chart.js should make this possible - its currently in alpha.

Comment: can you provide that link

Comment: Why same graphs are not showing in same HTML PAGE. I take the copy of the BAR Graph from another column and paste it in next column in same HTML Page - the graph doesnt display there. (CHART.JS GRAPH)

Comment: If you are asking about the v2.0 charts, the release is still in active development. There may be stuff broken because the syntax has changed slightly - all of which will be fixed / sorted out before the actual release. cheers!

Comment: I dont know whether it is V2.0 Charts, I am asking about the graph which you give me solution. When i tried to paste the Same Graph in another layer of same HTML page it is not working. Hope now you understand my question and can give me solution.

Comment: do you have the chart.js script added and the myChart element?

Comment: This is the code                                                                                <canvas id="mychart" width="645px" height="304"></canvas>
<script src="charts/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
var lineChartData = {
labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
datasets : [
{
fillColor : "#007ae1",
strokeColor : "#001ca8",
pointColor : "#007ae1",
pointStrokeColor : "#000",
data : [30,9,44,35,19,26,40]
},
]
}
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("mychart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
</script>

Comment: If i copy paste the same code in another cell of SAME HTML PAGE,  DISPLAYS only ONE CHART, NOT SHOWING THE OTHER ONE. The chart.js is the same which i downloaded from Internet. I didnt make any changes to that one. Kindly help me in resolving from this issue.

Comment: er... it's a bit difficult to figure out what's going on (esp. with all the uppercase in between :-)). Can you paste the sections into the fiddle, fork it and post a link?

Comment: Kindly go through these link, i pasted the code here... https://jsfiddle.net/sajeeshsachu/cfdt87cw/

Comment: The fiddle is missing the chart.js (you can add it under external resource). once you add that it works!

Comment: The same code that i used (SOLUTION FROM YOUR SIDE)........... http://jsfiddle.net/t0o07xbf/

Comment: Sorry. I'm not able to understand what you are having a problem with - could you post the code that does NOT work? It's difficult to figure out what's wrong with just information that this working code does not work if I paste it into xyz file without the xyz file.

Comment: Dear Friend, Now you have better understandings. https://jsfiddle.net/cfdt87cw/14/

Answer (score 0):

you can add this properties into your code:

```
scaleOverride : true,
scaleSteps : 5,
scaleStepWidth : 5,
scaleStartValue : 0,
```